# OpenCV & Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 ( for x64 )

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I have been trying to run OpenCV through MVS 2012 with no succeess.

Here is an error i get:

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core242d.lib' 1> 1>Build FAILED.

Could someone provide me a tutorial? or how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you built the libraries for 32bit and you are compiling in 64. Or the path you are linking is for 32bit libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post on [Using OpenCV 2.4.2 with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 (64-bit)](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/). With the step by step instructions provided, I think it should be pretty easy for you to get it done. Feel free to comment if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV 2.4 does not work well with Visual Studio 2012. I think that's why you always got problems. Actually, it used me a lot of time to make all things work. So I wrote a very simple tutorial about how to use OpenCV 2.43 in Visual Studio 2012. Please check it. Good luck. If you still have questions, ask me again.

> http://answers.opencv.org/question/6495/visual-studio-2012-and-rtlfreeheap-error/#6603

Comment: It would be best if you could add the essential info in the answer instead of an external link. This might be seen a link-only answer.

Comment: Yeah, I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic steps...

1. use cmake to create the .sln or the solution file ...make sure you **choose right the compiler** in cmake properly...use the address of the cmake file (CMakelist.txt) in the folder containing opencv files..
2. click on the .sln file (this will be found in the target folder whose path you have set in cmake to contain the build..) and open with VS2012
3. VS2012 will build your libraries and dlls...add the path of the dlls to the system variable PATH...put the path of the libs in the IDE..and the include files also..
4. restart VS2012 to make the changes in PATH variable to reflect

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options - one is to use the precompiled libraries and link them into your VS2012 projects.

The other is to use CMake to make the the right .SLN and .PRJX files so you can simply open them .SLN in VS2012 and compile everything for yourself.

Both have been discussed here, however, to add to the first option, you need to manually edit the top level CMAKElist.txt file with the following lines

```
if( MSVC ) # VS2012 doesn't support correctly the tuples yet
   add_definitions( /D _VARIADIC_MAX=10 )
 endif()
```

Before generating your solution files. This ensures that you don't have problems with the VARIADIC length issue with :tuple  - which Visual studio 2012 has issues with.

Answer (score 0):

there may be 2 option to solve your error:

1) You may use opencv 2.4.2 that may have some problems to connect with visual studio 2012
   so use newer version of opencv

2) You need to restart your visual studio 2012 so that it can reconfigure its Setting       as per requirements.