# OpenCV with VS2012 (Qt Support)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build OpenCV on windows 32bits following this [manual](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

- VS2012 as IDE.
- Qt support (built from sources according to the tutorial).
- phynx documentation.
- Tried to include CUDA support, but as of right now it is not compatatible with VS2012.

Everything goes fine until I get to the building part using the solution files created from cmake. For most modules i get the following error:

**LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\opencv_core249d.lib'**

with different files, but always error LNK1104.

When the compilation is complete the end result is something like:

Build completed. 9 succesful, 245 failed, 7 up-to-date, 0 skkiped.

Bottom line, I can't build opencv on vs2012, anyone got a tutorial or tips on this?

Comment: I think this thread could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474448/opencv-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-for-x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using Opencv2.4.9? opencv_core249d.lib indicates you are using that.
I'm going to post a tutorial on how to build opencv2.4.3 on VS2012, you can come to my blog a few days later. I'm going to publish it this weekend.
My blog post is at [How to compile opencv 2.4.3 x86 and x64 using Visual Studio 2012](http://www.ycshao.com/?p=668)

Comment: Actually no that is not the version I was triying to build, it was 2.4.3, I have no idea why the compiler is complaining about those particular files, my opencv files are downloaded trough Git. I just saw your blog, I will give a go and see if it works, thanks!.

Comment: I just read your blog and I can not find anything that I did not do when I was triying to built it myself, maybe it was my version of opencv, downloaded from Git. Right now I built a MinGW build of OpenCV under Qt Creator at the expense of loosing cuda and TBB.

Comment: I think in your case, opencv_core249d.lib fails to build so other application fail too. Maybe you can try stable version 2.4.3 if you don't rely on the latest feature.