# OpenCV & Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 issue with cmaklist.txt

Tags: opencv, cmake

when taking the advice of resolving the tuple::too many arguments issue that was posted here [OpenCV & Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 ( for x64 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474448/opencv-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-for-x64)

when i tried to add the
 `if( MSVC ) # VS2012 doesn't support correctly the tuples yet
   add_definitions( /D _VARIADIC_MAX=10 )
 endif()`

to the end of the top level cmakelists.txt i get this error-

Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "ï»¿".
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

My question is where should this code be inserted? what is the reason for this error?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `add_definitions` command looks OK.  You can also use

```
add_definitions(-D_VARIADIC_MAX=10)
```

but this shouldn't make any difference.

The error message you're seeing is related to CMake being unable to parse the CMakeCache.txt file in your build folder.

Try deleting the CMakeCache.txt and re-running CMake.